# Is the result of a Global MINLP Solver, a global optimum

Tags: optimization, solver, pyomo

I used Pyomo and couenne solver that is a global solver for MINLP. But the result is not global optimum!!
Is it possible that the result of a global solver don't be a global optimum?
What is the problem?

The solver log is:

```
Solver command line: ['C:\\Users\\~\\couenne.exe', 'C:\\Users\\~\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpv6y0s3cc.pyomo.nl', '-AMPL']
couenne: 
ANALYSIS TEST: Problem size before reformulation: 16 variables (6 integer), 37 constraints.
Problem size after  reformulation: 54 variables (6 integer), 37 constraints.
*****************************************************************************
This program contains Ipopt, a library for large-scale nonlinear optimization.

 Ipopt is released as open source code under the Common Public License (CPL).
         For more information visit http://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt ******************************************************************************
NOTE: You are using Ipopt by default with the MUMPS linear solver.

      Other linear solvers might be more efficient (see Ipopt documentation).
Cbc0031I 8 added rows had average density of 2

Cbc0013I At root node, 8 cuts changed objective from -20.3231 to -20.235 in 10 passes

Cbc0014I Cut generator 0 (Couenne convexifier cuts) - 48 row cuts average 2.0 elements, 2 column cuts (10 active)

Cbc0010I After 0 nodes, 0 on tree, 1e+050 best solution, best possible -20.235 (0.16 seconds)

Cbc0004I Integer solution of -10.0826 found after 831 iterations and 63 nodes (0.81 seconds)

Cbc0010I After 100 nodes, 38 on tree, -10.0826 best solution, best possible -15.9137 (0.89 seconds)

Cbc0004I Integer solution of -10.5219 found after 1264 iterations and 114 nodes (0.91 seconds)

Cbc0010I After 200 nodes, 26 on tree, -10.5219 best solution, best possible -11.899 (1.44 seconds)

Cbc0010I After 300 nodes, 29 on tree, -10.5219 best solution, best possible -10.9884 (1.61 seconds)

Cbc0010I After 400 nodes, 13 on tree, -10.5219 best solution, best possible -10.5235 (1.72 seconds)

Cbc0001I Search completed - best objective -10.52192111756512, took 3256 iterations and 479 nodes (1.80 seconds)

Cbc0035I Maximum depth 36, 0 variables fixed on reduced cost

 Couenne convexifier cuts was tried 939 times and created 3190 cuts of which 548 were active after adding rounds of cuts



    "Finished"
```

Comment: Couenne is somewhat rigorous (I know this sounds strange). For reasonable models, it should eventually prove global optimality. But unfortunately, I have seen it fail on some models (declaring optimal with a suboptimal solution). My suggestion: (1) show the solver log, (2) implement the model in GAMS or AMPL and submit to NEOS. You can easily try out a few global solvers that way (3) use a local solver but use a multistart strategy to get better solutions.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thanks for your reply. I edited my question and showed  the solver log. I wrote a gradient algorithm and I found some local optimum in my problem. I used Knitro (with multistart strategy) that is a local solver and its solution was worse than my algorithm(Gradient). I used Couenne  as a global solver but I got a solution worse than Knitro and Gradient!!
I need a global solver (also with free license) because I want to compare the solution of gradient with global optimum solution (or a solution better than Gradient).

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the log. So, I would try some other global solvers such as Baron and Antigone. Export the model as a GAMS model and submit to NEOS is very simple.